# PostGis tutorial

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, postgis

Кто-нибудь находил примеры использования postgis+spring+postgresql? Через гугл  конкретных примеров использования найти не смог. Если кто-нибудь знает такие статьи, то подетилитесь, пожалуйста. Язык статей не важен.

Comment: эм - https://postgis.net/docs/, Postgis это либа для Postgresql, что вам конкретно нужно от Spring, запросы?

Comment: ну да, например, хочу по координатам добавлять в базу данных конкретные места. На контроллер будут поступать координаты, затем эти координаты я хочу конвертировать в конкретное место и сохранить в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите `nativeQuery`

с использованием `JPARepository`:

```
@Query("SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING(-122.33 47.606, 0.0 51.5)'::geography, 'POINT(-21.96 64.15)'::geography)", nativeQuery = true)
String selectGeo();
```

С использованием `EntityManager`:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING(-122.33 47.606, 0.0 51.5)'::geography, 'POINT(-21.96 64.15)'::geography)");
```